# React Native 0.62.2 crashes on Android api 19

Tags: android, react-native

I created a react native project and tried to run it on emulator with android 4.4 (api 19) but it builds successfully but not able to open app.

[image: can't run the app]
This is my package.json libs:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
```

and as the **build.gradle** looks like it should work:

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
```

Comment: Any update on that? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: i couldn't find any answers and  changed the version.